# Problems installing operating system

Tags: system-installation

I have encountered a problem while trying to install ubuntu operating system on my laptop. The laptop is not able to boot from the CD even if I selected, "help me boot from CD" and by the way I was currently using windows 8

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have enabled UEFI boot on your machine. Try to enter BIOS and select legacy boot for your Ubuntu. There can be some problems though. I personally had to install both Windows and Ubuntu in Legacy mode, because dual boot didn't run with UEFI enabled.

Answer (score -1):

I experienced the same problem. These are the steps I took:

1. In the BIOS, turn the secure boot off
2. Also select legacy boot instead of UEFI boot.
3. Also check the boot order.

That *will* do the job.